# After formatting Windows 7 there is still dual-boot screen

Tags: 12.04, installation, windows-7, uninstall, format

I have installed Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10 on my PC and Ubuntu was installed using WUBI installer.

Today, I format my PC and installed Windows 7 and after restarting the PC, there is still displayed a dual-boot (Win 7 and Ubuntu) menu, but I do not have install Ubuntu.

Can anyone tell me what is wrong and why is there still a dual-boot screen? How can remove this dual boot and install new version Ubuntu along Windows 7? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Those entries are still showing because you installed Wubi (Ubuntu inside Windows) in a partition which you didn't format. As a result the Ubuntu boot information was at the root of the partition there (for example, if you installed in `E:`, the boot files are still in `E:`). Windows 7 scanned for other OSes  during installation and added Ubuntu in the list. (It is same as adding Windows XP).

> How can remove this dual boot and instal new version ubuntu along win 7? Can anyone help me with these?

I recommend removing the Ubuntu files at that partition, mainly `ubuntu.disk` and `swap.disk` file and then install Ubuntu via Wubi in the same old partition. Alternatively, You can just format that partition (You should backup your data first, if you have there) and install Ubuntu via Wubi there.